# Smart pythonic way of removing if elif on regular expressions

Tags: python

I have a series of reg expressions called in order. I need to check the first one, and then the second, then the third etc etc right the way until the end. I need to do some processed on the matched string, so I'm trying to avoid too much logic, but in python, unlike perl I do not think I can perform assignment in the `if-elif-elif`..blocks so I'll end up doing an assignment, then checking for a match and then getting the results of that match. For example:

```
m = re.search(patternA, string)
if m:
  stripped = m.group(0)
  xyz = stripped[45:67]
elif:
  m = re.search(patternB, string)
  if m:
    stripped = m.group(0)
    abc = stripped[5:7]
  elif:
     m = re.search(patternB, string)
     if m:
       stripped = m.group(0)
       txt = stripped[4:5]
     elif:
       ......
```

Ideally I'd like to find a better structure that ensures I preserve the ordering of the tested regular expressions, and also that I can incorporate the assignment into the if-then statements. So for example:

```
if (m = re.search(patternA, string)):
  stripped = m.group(0)
  xyz = stripped[45:67]
elif (m = re.search(patternB, string)):
  stripped = m.group(0)
  abc = stripped[5:7]
...
```

What is the most pythonic way of dealing with this? Thanks.

The use case is to read old data - very old data. However each string may include information about particular values and these are only present if the regular expression matches a particular pattern. So the variables extracted are highly dependent upon what matches.

Comment: Why the different targets to assign the result to, or the slices? Normally you'd use grouping to pick out the text you really want to extract.

Comment: As a hack you could write a function that accepts the result of `re.search()` and assigns it to a property of an object that you also pass in, returning `True` or `False`.  But eww.

Comment: @MartijnPieters there are different variables each set of positions/slices is dependent on reg expression.

Comment: @MartijnPieters I think what he means is that you can use a *capturing group* to pick out the text you really want.  Then you could just throw the regexes in a list and try each one (using a loop) until you get a match, then pull the text out of the first capturing group.

Comment: @cdhowie: the slicing can be addressed too (using `slice()` objects), but I really don't see why they are being used here. It is the assigning to totally different names here that is the bigger problem, and I cannot imagine why that was done.

Comment: Doesn't alternatation (`|`) with capturing work?

Comment: @Keith If `regxA|regxB` succeeded, how would you know which one you captured in order to select the correct slice?

Comment: Just for interest, the use case I have put above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (pattern, slice) in zip([patternA, patternB, patternC],
                            [slice(45,67), slice(5,7), slice(4,5)]):
    m = re.search(pattern, string)
    if m:
        value = m.group(0)[slice]
        break
else:
    # Handle no match found for any pattern here
```

This iterates over pairs of regular expressions and the relevant portion of their match until a match is found. If there is no match found, the `else` clause of the `for` loop will execute. The result of the match is found in `value` after the loop, regardless of which pattern matches.

Having different variables set based on which "branch" succeeds is not a great idea, since you won't necessarily know which variables are set at any given time. A dictionary would be a better idea if you really want separate labels for each match, since you can query which key or keys are set in a dictionary.

```
value = {}
for (pattern, slice, key) in zip([patternA, patternB, patternC],
                                 [slice(45,67), slice(5,7), slice(4,5)],
                                 ['abc', 'xyx', 'txt']):
    m = re.search(pattern, string)
    if m:
        value[key] = m.group(0)[slice]
        break
```

The general idea, though, is to note that your chain of `if` statements is like a hard-coded iteration, so you just need to identify which parts of each `if/elif` clause varies from the preceding ones, and create a list that you can iterate over instead.

Comment: I like it, its elegant. Only there a few variables per reg expression because there are multiple slices. Have to further iterate through those slices/variables.

Comment: +1: I can't believe I didn't know that [`slice()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#slice) exists!

Comment: zip is cool - learn't about it a long time ago but never used it in anger. In the end I used multiple zip to cope with the variable keys.